# Is it possible to implement the following in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Given an image of 5x5 by I(i, j) = |4-i-j| when i,j = 0,1,2,3,4.

and the following Prewitt operator :

```
               { {-1, 0, 1},
                 {-1, 0, 1},
                 {-1, 0, 1} }

               { {-1, -1, -1},
                 {0, 0, 0},
                 {1, 1, 1} }
```

How do I calculate the gradient ? [magnitude and direction] (with Prewitt operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

- Write your own convolution function
- Use `imgradient`
- Use `imfilter`
- Use `conv2`

Comment: can you show me example with code please i am a newbie in mathlab

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient.html Prewitt is one of the options for the `method` parameter.